# at command not found

Tags: linux, scheduling, job-control, at

Following on from [Cron job for 7 days alone not followed by multiple weeks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310774/cron-job-for-7-days-alone-not-followed-by-multiple-weeks/310798), I am trying to use `at` but it shows `at: command not found`.

By default it seems that Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo) does not come with `at`. However, I can run `cron` jobs.

What package do I need to install? How would I do that?

Comment: Presumably, `at` is not shipped with RHEL so you will need to install it, as per the error message...

Comment: @jasonwran Thank you, Captain Obvious :-) The problem is, how is one supposed to know that "at" comes in its own package, and not part of something else, and if so, just what is that something else?

Answer (score 5):

I dont have a RedHat right here, but on Debian the package is called `at`.

Try

```
yum install at
```

*(and then this question might be deleted. Its kind of obvious)*

Comment: _It is not at all obvious._ Many programs that formerly came pre-installed now come as part of some other package. You might, for example, need to say `yum install schedule-utils`, then you'd get `at`, `batch`, and who knows what else. And `yum search at` returns a listing with every package with "at" in the name, quite a long list, let me assure you. OK, we're lucky this time, `yum install at` actually works. But do I have permission to strangle the goofball who decided to leave it out in the first place?